# send request using Fetch method

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I need to send request using 'fetch' method. I need to send below data to my header

[image]

I need to send below data in request body

[image]

i am trying to do it using below code. but actually I have not proper idea to do it. can u help me.

```
 fetch("http://disaida.com/api/endpoint/", {
  method: "post",
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    PREPAY: ppy,
    InputParameters: int
  })
})
.then( (response) => { 
  
});
```

Comment: your body looks incorrect

Comment: Also please do some research; It is well documented function https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data format is incorrect.
TRY
Also, based on your description, you might have to add the cookie property to your header

```js
let data = {
    PREPAY: {
     InputParameters: {
     P_USER_NAME : "SANJEEWA.LAKNATH1@HUAWEI.COM"
     }
    }
  }

fetch("http://disaida.com/api/endpoint/", {
  method: "post",
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(data)
})
.then( (response) => { 
console.log("RR"+response.json())
}).catch(err => console.log("error",err));
```